# Create Bayesian Network and learn parameters with Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, probability, bayesian-networks

I'm searching for the most appropriate tool for python3.x on Windows to create a Bayesian Network, learn its parameters from data and perform the inference.

The network structure I want to define myself as follows:
[image]

It is taken from [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6697180) paper.

All the variables are discrete (and can take only 2 possible states) except "Size" and "GraspPose", which are continuous and should be modeled as Mixture of Gaussians.

Authors use *Expectation-Maximization algorithm* to learn the parameters for conditional probability tables and *Junction-Tree algorithm* to compute the exact inference.

As I understand all is realised in MatLab with Bayes Net Toolbox by Murphy.

I tried to search something similar in python and here are my results:

1. Python Bayesian Network Toolbox http://sourceforge.net/projects/pbnt.berlios/ (http://pbnt.berlios.de/). Web-site doesn't work, project doesn't seem to be supported.
2. BayesPy https://github.com/bayespy/bayespy
   I think this is what I actually need, but I fail to find some examples similar to my case, to understand how to approach construction of the network structure.
3. PyMC seems to be a powerful module, but I have problems with importing it on Windows 64, python 3.3. I get error when I install development version

   WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.

UPDATE:

4. libpgm (http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/). Exactly what I need, unfortunately not supported by python 3.x
5. Very interesting actively developing library: PGMPY. Unfortunately continuous variables and learning from data is not supported yet. https://github.com/pgmpy/pgmpy/

Any advices and concrete examples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I've never tried it but you might check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BNfinder/2.0.4

Comment: @runDOSrun thanks. Unfortunately seems not to be ported to python 3.x

Comment: Have you tried scikit-learn? http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html Seems to have what you want, and many other ML algorithms that work in python 3.x.

Comment: I don't think scikit-learn's naive Bayes does inference, as the asker wants? However it seems libpgm now supports Python 3: https://github.com/CyberPoint/libpgm

Answer (score 12):

It looks like [pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) was recently updated to include Bayesian Networks.  I haven't tried it myself, but the interface looks nice and sklearn-ish.

Comment: Yes, looks very promising, thank you. I will give it a try. Looking forward when continuous variables will be also supported.

Comment: @Spu Did you try it? What were your experiences?

Answer (score 6):

Try the [bnlearn library](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn), it contains many functions to learn parameters from data and perform the inference.

```
pip install bnlearn
```

Your use-case would be like this:

```
# Import the library
import bnlearn

# Define the network structure
edges = [('task', 'size'),
         ('lat var', 'size'),
         ('task', 'fill level'),
         ('task', 'object shape'),
         ('task', 'side graspable'),
         ('size', 'GrasPose'),
         ('task', 'GrasPose'),
         ('fill level', 'GrasPose'),
         ('object shape', 'GrasPose'),
         ('side graspable', 'GrasPose'),
         ('GrasPose', 'latvar'),
]

# Make the actual Bayesian DAG
DAG = bnlearn.make_DAG(edges)

# DAG is stored in adjacency matrix
print(DAG['adjmat'])

# target           task   size  lat var  ...  side graspable  GrasPose  latvar
# source                                 ...                                  
# task            False   True    False  ...            True      True   False
# size            False  False    False  ...           False      True   False
# lat var         False   True    False  ...           False     False   False
# fill level      False  False    False  ...           False      True   False
# object shape    False  False    False  ...           False      True   False
# side graspable  False  False    False  ...           False      True   False
# GrasPose        False  False    False  ...           False     False    True
# latvar          False  False    False  ...           False     False   False
# 
# [8 rows x 8 columns]

# No CPDs are in the DAG. Lets see what happens if we print it.
bnlearn.print_CPD(DAG)
# >[BNLEARN.print_CPD] No CPDs to print. Use bnlearn.plot(DAG) to make a plot.

# Plot DAG. Note that it can be differently orientated if you re-make the plot.
bnlearn.plot(DAG)
```

[image: Pre-defined DAG]

Now we need the data to learn its parameters. Suppose these are stored in your *df*. The variable names in the data-file must be present in the DAG.

```
# Read data
df = pd.read_csv('path_to_your_data.csv')

# Learn the parameters and store CPDs in the DAG. Use the methodtype your desire. Options are maximumlikelihood or bayes.
DAG = bnlearn.parameter_learning.fit(DAG, df, methodtype='maximumlikelihood')
# CPDs are present in the DAG at this point.
bnlearn.print_CPD(DAG)

# Start making inferences now. As an example:
q1 = bnlearn.inference.fit(DAG, variables=['lat var'], evidence={'fill level':1, 'size':0, 'task':1})
```

Below is a working example with a demo dataset (sprinkler). You can play around with this.

```
# Import example dataset
df = bnlearn.import_example('sprinkler')
print(df)
#      Cloudy  Sprinkler  Rain  Wet_Grass
# 0         0          0     0          0
# 1         1          0     1          1
# 2         0          1     0          1
# 3         1          1     1          1
# 4         1          1     1          1
# ..      ...        ...   ...        ...
# 995       1          0     1          1
# 996       1          0     1          1
# 997       1          0     1          1
# 998       0          0     0          0
# 999       0          1     1          1

# [1000 rows x 4 columns]


# Define the network structure
edges = [('Cloudy', 'Sprinkler'),
         ('Cloudy', 'Rain'),
         ('Sprinkler', 'Wet_Grass'),
         ('Rain', 'Wet_Grass')]

# Make the actual Bayesian DAG
DAG = bnlearn.make_DAG(edges)
# Print the CPDs
bnlearn.print_CPD(DAG)
# [BNLEARN.print_CPD] No CPDs to print. Use bnlearn.plot(DAG) to make a plot.
# Plot the DAG
bnlearn.plot(DAG)
```

[image]

```
# Parameter learning on the user-defined DAG and input data
DAG = bnlearn.parameter_learning.fit(DAG, df)

# Print the learned CPDs
bnlearn.print_CPD(DAG)

# [BNLEARN.print_CPD] Independencies:
# (Cloudy _|_ Wet_Grass | Rain, Sprinkler)
# (Sprinkler _|_ Rain | Cloudy)
# (Rain _|_ Sprinkler | Cloudy)
# (Wet_Grass _|_ Cloudy | Rain, Sprinkler)
# [BNLEARN.print_CPD] Nodes: ['Cloudy', 'Sprinkler', 'Rain', 'Wet_Grass']
# [BNLEARN.print_CPD] Edges: [('Cloudy', 'Sprinkler'), ('Cloudy', 'Rain'), ('Sprinkler', 'Wet_Grass'), ('Rain', 'Wet_Grass')]
# CPD of Cloudy:
# +-----------+-------+
# | Cloudy(0) | 0.494 |
# +-----------+-------+
# | Cloudy(1) | 0.506 |
# +-----------+-------+
# CPD of Sprinkler:
# +--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# | Cloudy       | Cloudy(0)          | Cloudy(1)          |
# +--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# | Sprinkler(0) | 0.4807692307692308 | 0.7075098814229249 |
# +--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# | Sprinkler(1) | 0.5192307692307693 | 0.2924901185770751 |
# +--------------+--------------------+--------------------+
# CPD of Rain:
# +---------+--------------------+---------------------+
# | Cloudy  | Cloudy(0)          | Cloudy(1)           |
# +---------+--------------------+---------------------+
# | Rain(0) | 0.6518218623481782 | 0.33695652173913043 |
# +---------+--------------------+---------------------+
# | Rain(1) | 0.3481781376518219 | 0.6630434782608695  |
# +---------+--------------------+---------------------+
# CPD of Wet_Grass:
# +--------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
# | Rain         | Rain(0)            | Rain(0)             | Rain(1)             | Rain(1)             |
# +--------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
# | Sprinkler    | Sprinkler(0)       | Sprinkler(1)        | Sprinkler(0)        | Sprinkler(1)        |
# +--------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
# | Wet_Grass(0) | 0.7553816046966731 | 0.33755274261603374 | 0.25588235294117645 | 0.37910447761194027 |
# +--------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
# | Wet_Grass(1) | 0.2446183953033268 | 0.6624472573839663  | 0.7441176470588236  | 0.6208955223880597  |
# +--------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+

# Make inference
q1 = bnlearn.inference.fit(DAG, variables=['Wet_Grass'], evidence={'Rain':1, 'Sprinkler':0, 'Cloudy':1})

# +--------------+------------------+
# | Wet_Grass    |   phi(Wet_Grass) |
# +==============+==================+
# | Wet_Grass(0) |           0.2559 |
# +--------------+------------------+
# | Wet_Grass(1) |           0.7441 |
# +--------------+------------------+

print(q1.values)
# array([0.25588235, 0.74411765])
```

More examples can be found on documentation the pages of [bnlearn](https://erdogant.github.io/bnlearn) or [read the blog](https://link.medium.com/MC4yYkK3Fnb).

Comment: This is very nice! thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a similar library, and I found that the [pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) is  a good one. Thanks [James Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938325/james-atwood)

Here is an example how to use it.

```
from pomegranate import *
import numpy as np

mydb=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,2,5],[1,2,6],[1,3,8],[2,3,8],[1,2,4]])

bnet = BayesianNetwork.from_samples(mydb)

print(bnet.node_count())

print(bnet.probability([[1,2,3]]))
print (bnet.probability([[1,2,8]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

For pymc's g++ problem, I highly recommend to get g++ installation done, it would hugely boost the sampling process, otherwise you will have to live with this warning and sit there for 1 hour for a 2000 sampling process.

The way to get the warning fixed is:
1. get g++ installed, download cywing and get g++ install, you can google that. To check this, just go to "cmd" and type "g++", if it says "require input file", great, you got g++ installed.
2. install python package: mingw, libpython
3. install python package: theano

this should get this problem fixed.

I am currently working on the same problem with you, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, as always, but I've wrapped up the BayesServer Java API using JPype; it might not have all the functionality that you need but you would create the above network using something like:

```
from bayesianpy.network import Builder as builder
import bayesianpy.network

nt = bayesianpy.network.create_network()

# where df is your dataframe
task = builder.create_discrete_variable(nt, df, 'task')

size = builder.create_continuous_variable(nt, 'size')
grasp_pose = builder.create_continuous_variable(nt, 'GraspPose')

builder.create_link(nt, size, grasp_pose)
builder.create_link(nt, task, grasp_pose)

for v in ['fill level', 'object shape', 'side graspable']:
    va = builder.create_discrete_variable(nt, df, v)
    builder.create_link(nt, va, grasp_pose)
    builder.create_link(nt, task, va)

# write df to data store
with bayesianpy.data.DataSet(df, bayesianpy.utils.get_path_to_parent_dir(__file__), logger) as dataset:
    model = bayesianpy.model.NetworkModel(nt, logger)
    model.train(dataset)

    # to query model multi-threaded
    results = model.batch_query(dataset, [bayesianpy.model.QueryModelStatistics()], append_to_df=False)
```

I'm not affiliated with Bayes Server - and the Python wrapper is not 'official' (you can use the Java API via Python directly). My wrapper makes some assumptions and places limitations on functions that I don't use very much. The repo is here: [github.com/morganics/bayesianpy](http://github.com/morganics/bayesianpy)