# Is there python library that can learn the parameters of a given dynamic bayesian network?

Tags: python, matlab, bayesian-networks

As the title said, what I need is a python library not Matlab's BNT.

BNT is quite strong, but most of the time, I use python to clean data, and recently I found that use two different language to do one thing usually make the problem much more complex. So I want a python library that can fit the parameters of DBNs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Bayesian Network and learn parameters with Python3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431350/create-bayesian-network-and-learn-parameters-with-python3-x)

Comment: Thank you.I saw that, but these libraries do not support DBNs learning.